# Question about introduction of variables in proof of SVD in Trefethen and Bau.

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

[image]

I have understood as far as marked with the red line. I am trying to understand the proof that there exists an SVD for all matrices. I don't understand why there is needed for an orthonormal extension of u and v. I understand that $U_1$ and $V_1$ are column vectors.

I understand part of equation 4.5 and what I understand is:

$A=U\Sigma V^*$

$U_1AV_1^*=\Sigma$

And thus:
$U_1AV_1^*=\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

Thus far I understand but why is b introduced and why is W* introduced?? What does the proof seek to do at this point?

Last part of the proof.

[image]

Comment: The product $U_1AV_1^*$ does not (generally) make sense. $U_1^*AV_1 = \pmatrix{\sigma_1\\ 0}$ is only correct if $V_1$ has only one column, which is not always the case

Comment: The equation 
$$
U_1^*AV_1 = \pmatrix{\sigma_1 & w^*\\0&B}
$$
is meant to convey that $U_1^*AV_1$  is a matrix for which we know the first column but have no additional information. $B$ and $w^*$ are simply the "rest of the entries" of this matrix.

Comment: @BenGrossmann   Thank you I understood. I have a followup question but I did not want to make a new post. Can you perhaps explain the red box in the image below.  I understood everything until that point. B has dimensions (1-n) and (1-m) and if n=m=1 then the dimension is $0x0$? How can the SVD be used to show the existence of SVD, is that not circular reasoning? I don't understand the proof.

I did the last by hand and saw that it ads up but what is the point of this??

$A=U_1\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1 &0  \\
 1 & U_2\Sigma_2V_2^*
\end{pmatrix}V_1*$

Comment: This is an inductive proof, so we need a base case. I believe the authors are implicitly using the fact that the SVD trivially exists for $1 \times 1$ matrices: if $A$ is a non-negative number (rather, "$1 \times 1$ matrix"), take $U = V = 1$. Otherwise, take $U = -1$ and $V = 1$. In either case, $\Sigma = |A|$ (i.e. the absolute value of the number $A$).

Comment: Can you explain this part? "If n = I or m = 1, we are done. Otherwise, the submatrix B describes the action of A on the subspace orthogonal to $v_1$."  
And the dimension of B is (1,1) but it said at the beginning that B has dimensions (1-n) and (1-m)  so B is (0,0)?

Comment: When they say "we are done", they mean that there is no need to use the partitioning of the matrix $U_1AV_1^*$. In other words, the cases where $n = 1$ or $m = 1$ form the base cases for induction (my earlier comment that they are using the case where $n=1$ **and** $m=1$ as a bases case is apparently incorrect).